# What is the equivalent of $scope and $scope.watchcollection in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am trying to migrate the Angular 1 application to angular 2 with the help of UpgradeModule and downgradecomponent .

While converting controller to component.ts , I am facing problems as i am not sure how to write alternative of scope and watchcollection in angular2 .

Could someone let me know equivalent of $scope and $scope.watchcollection in Angular 2?

Comment: start with reading [Angular’s $digest is reborn in the newer version of Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e)

Answer (score 1):

The parallel for $scope in Angular is the "this" keyword. Angular's new change detection coupled with shared services leveraging it's improved DI eliminate the need for a RootScope or local $scope for that matter.

The watchCollection is replaced in a similar way. Entities within the scope of your class WILL be evaluated unless you go out of your way to not have them evaluated or modify the default change detection strategy to Push.

Hope this helps,
Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2.0 is using `this` instead of `$scope`.

One of the major changes coming in 2.0 is the death of the controller, and a new emphasis on components. Big advantage of moving towards component-based apps is that it's easier to define their interfaces; plus, HTML elements already have an easily mappable interface in events, attributes, and properties.

See the Migration of AngularJS 1.3 to 2.0 [here](http://paislee.io/migrating-to-angularjs-2-0/). Also see the complete documentation of Angular 2.0 [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1XQP0_NTzCUcFweauLlkZpbbhNVYbYy156oD--KLmXsk/preview?slide=id.p)